# How do I properly embed flash files with SSL active?

Tags: flash, ssl, embed

I recently added an SSL certificate onto my website. I've changed everything to https and I am getting the green secure bar. However, on my pages with flash content, I receive the error "your connection to this site is not fully secure". I discovered that my flash embed code is causing this. How do I properly add a flash file so that I can make my site show the green bar?

here's my embed code:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="https://www.example.com/file.swf"  width="700" height="520">
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer after digging around. Here's the proper way to embed a flash file on an SSL site:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="https://www.example.com/swf.swf"  
width="640" height="480">
<param name="movie" value="https://www.example.com/swf.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high"/>
</object>
```